# Adding space next to column title in SP 2010 custom list

Tags: title

I was able to do this previously in a different custom list but now it is not working. What I did was I created hard space in Word by pressing ctrl+shift+space. I copied that next the the column title, saved it, and it created a space next to the title. The purpose is to expand that column so we can read the contents of that column more easily. I'm doing that again now in a new custom list in the same sharepoint site but it is not working. Any idea why it's not working? What should I check and is there another alternative to hard space? I do not have SharePoint designer. It's not allowed in our company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite way is to add a CEWP to the view page and add the following script:

```
$("div.ms-vh-div[name='Title']").parent().css("width","25%")
```

If that's not your cup of tea, you can go the SharePoint Designer route listed here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

It's says 2013, but it works in 2010 as well.
Kind of a pain if you ask me though.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that I do not have a sharepoint designer.